# Evolution 3.10.4 password nuisance

Tags: password, email, evolution, keyrings

I have been using `evolution' since 2007. This summer evolution has started, for no apparent reason, to ask for mail account passwords and key-ring passwords at 5 minute intervals. Can Anyone tell me how to cure this "illness" and how can the "key-ring" be disabled altogether. I have always been warned NOT to use key-ring utilities as they are prime hacker targets. (Using Kubuntu 14.04 and Netrunner 14).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the keyring. Evolution requires gnome-keyring, as that is where it stores the password secrets for your accounts. Whomever warned you to not use keyring utilities is very misguided. There's a difference between the local keyring on your device, and a cloud based keyring service. The latter can be risky because there is no clear answer as to how a proprietary service is protecting your data.

To stop it asking for your password all the time, go to the *Account* settings for your account, switch to the *Receiving Options*, and ensure that the option to *Check for new messages every XX minutes* is disabled. You may also want to disable the *Use Quick Resync if the server supports it* and *Listen for server change notifications* options.

Comment: This does not explain the change of behaviour of Evolution in the last 6 months. I am not persuaded that the use of a local key-ring is now safe.  Good bye Evolution, and hello Thunderbird.

Comment: Well, whatever. Maybe you enabled the setting to auto-check for messages every 5 minutes or some other similar feature. Evolution certainly doesn't ask me for a password every 5 minutes. The keyring is perfectly safe. If you don't think so, you shouldn't be using Thunderbird then, it has its own keyring. KDE has a keyring too, called KWallet.